# Procedimiento en MySQL para insertar datos en forma de bucle

Tags: mysql, sql

Me explico:
Necesito insertar 88 registros en una base de datos en donde casi todos los campos tienen el mismo dato. No quiero perder el tiempo en insertarlo 100 veces manualmente. Ejemplo:

````
 ```INSERT INTO porcion (porcion, medida, idalimentos) VALUES (100, 'grs.', 1); ```
 ```INSERT INTO porcion (porcion, medida, idalimentos) VALUES (100, 'grs.', 2); ```
 ```INSERT INTO porcion (porcion, medida, idalimentos) VALUES (100, 'grs.', 3); ```
````

Solo cambia el último dato. (Ignorar que tengo un autoincrementador).
No se si esto se llama Trigger, o Procedimiento almacenado, la verdad que solo sé SQL básico.

Comment: Las sentencias de `insert` son atómicas, debes generar 1 por una, no significa que debas ejecutarlas también así ya que puedes construir un lote con los 88 `insert` en una cadena y ejecutar el lote completo. Otra alternativa puede ser el `insert into`, pero de cualquier forma deberías dar más detalles,¿esto dónde, cuando y como lo necesitarías hacer?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar un bucle While

```
delimiter $$
CREATE procedure ej()
  begin
    define i int;
    set i = 1;
    while i<=100 do
      INSERT INTO porcion (porcion, medida, idalimentos) VALUES (100, 'grs.', i);
      set i=i+1;
    end while;
  end$$
delimiter ;
```